# How to read/write a hash from a file in ruby?

Tags: ruby, yaml, file-handling

I want to store data of countries in a file and read that data. I tried to write it in filename.yml file but I am not able to get each hash separately to perform specific operation. Have a look what I tried

```
    require 'yaml'
    
    def addData
        puts 'Enter country name :'
        name = gets.chop.to_s
        puts 'Enter population in billion :'
        population = gets.chop.to_s
        puts 'Enter GDP in lakh crore USD:'
        gdp = gets.chop.to_s
        puts 'Enter army strength:'
        army_strength = gets.chop.to_s
        puts 'Enter state of country:'
        state = gets.chop.to_s
    
        country = Hash.new
        country = { "name" => name , "population" => population , "gdp" => gdp , "army_strength" => army_strength , "state" => state }
        
        arr_country.push(country)
        # Writing to the file 
        File.open('filename.yml','a') { |f| YAML.dump(country, f) }
    end
    
    def readData
    
        File.open('filename.yml') { 
            |f|.each {
            arr = YAML.load(f)
                if arr
                    puts arr
                    puts arr.class
                end
            }
        }
    end
    
    while true
        puts '1. Write','2. Read','3.Exit'
        opt = gets.chop.to_i
        if (opt>2)
            return
        end
    
        case opt
        when 1
            addData
        when 2
            readData    
        end
    end
```

But it's not working, what would be the best way ?

Comment: If someone can share a working code for similar functionality,  that would be great help.

Comment: Have you put in breakpoints to see what you are actually getting?

Comment: You should reduce this down to a simpler example, the `puts` etc. are needed to answer the question, the indenting is also tabs not spaces.

Comment: Also take a look at [`YAML::Store`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html) which is a less known, but useful way to do this

Comment: "it's not working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the minor mistakes, that are mentioned above, you might have most success using the `load_stream` function from YAML, rather than `load`

```
def readData
  File.open('filename.yml') do |f|
    arr = YAML.load_stream(f)
    if arr
      puts arr
      puts arr.class
    end
  end
end
```

While this is not how I would do it, it will allow you to append to the file, from any source, as long as it remains compatible with YAML.

My preference would be to use a database.

the resulting full code, on my system (run through rubocop) is:

```
require 'yaml'

def add_data
  puts 'Enter country name :'
  name = gets.chop.to_s
  puts 'Enter population in billion :'
  population = gets.chop.to_s
  puts 'Enter GDP in lakh crore USD:'
  gdp = gets.chop.to_s
  puts 'Enter army strength:'
  army_strength = gets.chop.to_s
  puts 'Enter state of country:'
  state = gets.chop.to_s

  country = {}
  country = { 'name' => name, 'population' => population, 'gdp' => gdp, 'army_strength' => army_strength, 'state' => state }

  # Writing to the file
  File.open('filename.yml', 'a') { |f| YAML.dump(country, f) }
end

def read_data
  arr = []
  File.open('filename.yml') do |f|
    arr = YAML.load_stream(f)
  end
  return unless arr

  puts arr
  puts arr.class
end

loop do
  puts '1. Write', '2. Read', '3.Exit'
  opt = gets.chop.to_i
  break if opt > 2

  case opt
  when 1
    add_data
  when 2
    read_data
  end
end
```

Comment: It's working fine sir. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `f.each` does not make sense. `f` is the file object, and `each` processes each line and tries to interpret each line as a separate YAML expression. However, your whole file consists of a single YAML expression.

You could do something like:

```
country = YAML.load(File.read('filename.yaml'))
```

Comment: It worked but I got only first hash. I have added more than 1 hashes in file but I am getting only first hash in ' country ' object. How can I get all the hashes one by one ?

Comment: For your reference I have following data in filename.yml

---
name: gfd
population: gfd
gdp: gfd
army_strength: gfd
state: fd
---
name: hg
population: hg
gdp: hg
army_strength: hg
state: hg
---
name: tr
population: gf
gdp: hg
army_strength: jh
state: gf

Comment: Since you have an array of Country objects, I would write out the whole array in a single YAML-dump if you want to get the whole array back anyway. If you **don't want** this, but want to restore only **certain array elements**, you would have to break the file apart into individual pieces, each holding the hash for one country. This is cumbersome. In this case, I would perhaps use a separate file for each country object.

Comment: Each time I am creating a hash and appending into file. After reading file, I am getting only  first hash and not array hashes. ( country.class is Hash ) . May be I have to make some changes in addData function while pushing data into file

Comment: I know. That's why I suggested to do it differently, and to write the whole array in one piece. If you prefer your current approach, I would at least write some marker into the file after each array element, so that you can find the individual pieces easier when reading the file back. But is there a particular reason why you want to do this?

Comment: No any reason. I want to develop a command line application and everytime user adds data of new country, it has to be added in file. Any suitable approach would be fine. Infact I used a CSV file instead of yml and it's working fine.

Comment: For this type of "incremental update", I would then write a separator string between the elements, so that you can know when reading, where one element ends and the next one starts. You could also use a separate file for each element and have the element index in the filename. BTW, are the country names guaranteed to be different? In this case, maybe having the data as a hash from country name as key, with country data as value would be more logical.